# Smart strings - like string literals but not and referencing an object - typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm most like not asking Google the correct question, so maybe someone who has done something similar can point me in the correct direction?

Let's example with the basic bit of code:

```js
const var1 = "abc";
console.log(`var is: ${var1}`);
```

If you were to incorrectly reference the variable in the string literal, you'd get an error.

What I am trying to do is similar but for a function/method.

```js
public format(message: string, meta: object) {
  // do blah here to format
}
format("this var: {var1}", {
  var1: "abc"
});
```

I want to have VSCode highlight the `var1` reference from the passed in object dynamically (however that isn't the main thing).

I need to be able to have typescript validate the object and string similar to that of a string literal on compilation.
So if you were to mistype the reference `{variable}` in the message, but not define a the variable in the meta object, it would error out.

Thanks

Comment: You _cannot_ reference a local variable name dynamically. This also means that local variable names _cannot_ be used in string literal types. So this isn't possible as is.

Comment: @AlexWayne - Let me confirm, you're saying `const var1 = "abc"; console.log('var is: ${var1}');` is not possible as is?

If it's possible using the TS compiler (string literals), then it must be possible to do it another way.

Comment: @AlexWayne haha :P Fair enough. What I am trying to do is basically what the TS compiler already does, just in a different way and without spending hours/days digging into the TS source code to work it out

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://tsplay.dev/mAQVQm It that is close your needs I can write up a proper answer

Comment: @AlexWayne Bloody hell you're good!  
Yes exactly what I was looking for!!!!  
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript template string literal types are so cool.

You can parse the string literal type for params, and use that to enforce your types.

```
type ParamsFromString<T extends string> =
  T extends `${ infer Pre }{${ infer Param }}${ infer Post }`
    ? Param | ParamsFromString<`${Pre}${Post}`>
    : never
```

- Line 1: This type accepts a `string` type `T`. This is the format string literal type.
- Line 2: This checks if the string matches the format that contains a param. If it does, then infer the part before the match as `Pre`, the part after as `Post` and the param name itself as `Param`.
- Line 3: This does two things. First, it returns the param name found. And second, it looks for more params. But to avoid finding the same param again, we make a new string literal that is just the `Pre` and `Post` concatenated. Then we return the param we found and all other params as a union with `|`.
- Line 4: Either the format string has no params, or we already found them all, so return `never` since there is nothing to find.

Testing that out:

```
type Test = ParamsFromString<'foo {bar} {baz}'>
// "bar" | "baz"
```

You can then use that type in a function like so:

```
function format<T extends string>(
  message: T,
  meta: Record<ParamsFromString<T>, string>
) {
  // do blah here to format
}
```

Here the format string is accepted as a string literal type as `T`. Then the object passed in must have keys that are the params derived from that string.

Proof:

```
format("this var: {var1}", { var1: "abc" }); // fine
format("this var: {var1}", { bad: "abc" }); // type error
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM4DEEHtkGVgICWAdgOYA8AKlBAB7ATEAmqUqBJpAfFALwBQUKAHphUAMIALCAGMA1lEIAzKMEmFW7ImUXEZAGwCuTCKzhQwiFABoocZrqUQEq6RavIoxFBGuCRYnCsAO4Q+vp2rGrQWpxQAEYQSlgI0PZMdkoMCP7UdAzMrAAGACQA3o7OsKlQAL5l5ZUu8EietbWNJE7NWOx1Rfz+QqJQAILurTS0GsCsJK4xHGS2qFhQqcCGCMSKwJF2UIbEhFg7oJCucMBDAboGxqZ24VBY0S6WrXNnbrE6wYRqVwaCYodYQZBYABuECYADobgB+WAeKAAH2Rn0wOHw2gopTKMFSHQJvWAtSKXEGQmGYgAcmsPihWHQZroFqhFriVmsNlsdsQINCEPDqVAAFxeQXOQbnaCUUx7XgYplYvBLCgAcmSazK8UQtSgurgAC9ahrKSMhAA9BGDJRHGTAE47ZIIZBXKhTAosNjqrgACmQplQcFIEAllFsQeAcAlACVZCkmOQWirsGrcVQuCs-QBKQ3+EZMNbxfRwSRQaQ1YBrV3u661O0pev+gBEamBkMQErKXYQAEZaq3bBU+-2Ja24PEZK26rmANy3JQkCD8OtXNsd1h9ntjocjhJwJgTqczueLkaymgIbAIIA)